# WooCommerce: One term for Many Product Attributes

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, terms, customization

I am using WooCommerce Product Attributes to show mobile phones specifications.

[image]

For that I have created woocommerce product attributes like OS, Resolution, Color, Weight, Has Fingerprint, Has Dual Flash etc.

Now the attributes are stored using Terms in the backend.

I am now having a case where **Has Fingerprint** and **Has Dual Flash** has the values/terms "YES" which I am unable to store because WooCommerce says the term "YES" already exists. How can I achieve so that both can have YES values?

Comment: did you create them as separate attributes? If you did, they shouldn't conflict with each other since they are just separate taxonomies in the backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand "product attributes" are basically taxonomies so in your case "Has Fingerprint", "Has Dual Flash" are taxonomies which can contain different terms and these terms should be unique, you can't store terms with same name.

Now right now you have 2 different Taxonomies, so there should not be issue of having 2 same terms with 2 different taxonomies. Just make sure you are not adding "Yes" to same taxonomy.